# I can't figure out why my image will not repaint

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, paint, picturebox

My images is definitally moving, but no matter what I do, I can not get it so the image repaints! The GameManger paints the cat, and the form1 passes the paint args and object to gamemanager.

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GameManager myGM = new GameManager();
        int dir = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newGame();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.myGM != null)
                this.myGM.paint(e.Graphics);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgMouse.Images[0], pointXMouse, pointYMouse);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], 50, 100);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgCheese.Images[0], 75, 100);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                dir = 0;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }
        }
        public void newGame()
        {
            timer1.Start();
            myGM.newGame(imgCat, imgMouse, imgCheese, this);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
        public int getDir()
        {
            return dir;
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class GameManager
    {
        Form1 myForm;
        Cat ca1 = new Cat();
        Mouse m = new Mouse();
        Cheese ch = new Cheese();
        int amount = 5;
        int catdir = 0;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        public ImageList imgCat = new ImageList();
        public ImageList imgMouse = new ImageList();
        public ImageList imgCheese = new ImageList();

        public void newGame(ImageList cat, ImageList mouse, ImageList cheese, Form1 form)
        {
            imgCat = cat;
            imgMouse = mouse;
            imgCheese = cheese;
            myForm = form;
            time.Start();
        }

        public void move()
        {
            ca1.Move(amount, catdir);
            m.Move(amount, catdir);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation());
        }

        private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move();
            getDir();
            myForm.Refresh();
        }
        public void getDir()
        {
            catdir = myForm.getDir();
        }
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class Cat: Moveable
    {
        Random myCLoc = new Random();
        private Moveable myCatMove;
        public Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        int dir = 0;

        public void Move(int n, int d)
        {
            dir = d;
            if (dir == 0)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y - n;
            }
            if (dir == 1)
            {
                p.X = p.X + n;
            }
            if (dir == 2)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y + n;
            }
            if (dir == 3)
            {
                p.X = p.X - n;
            }
        }
        public void changeDirection()
        {
        }

        public Point getLocation()
        {
            return p;
        }

        public void paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do it will just NOT REPAINT!

Comment: LOL, sorry. I have been working on this all day today for school. I could litterally probably do everything else by myself. I just can't figure this freaking move paint crap out.

Comment: Sorry, if it seems like I have been asking too much. I can leave if you would like...

Comment: I was only teasing :)

Comment: So did you actually get this fixed?...

Comment: Yes, It turned out that my timer time was not linked to the time_tick method, so nothing would move or paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `time.Tick +=new EventHandler(time_Tick);` to the GameManager constructor, apparently that is how a timer gets connected the time_tick method.

Answer (score 1):

Doublecheck if the timer is enabled and PictureBox.Paint event is fired (don't be afraid to use debugger). If it won't help try not to use `PictureBox.Paint` event and `Refresh` method, but call `myGM.paint` directly in Timer.Tick handler

Comment: How do I call myGM.paint in TImer.Tick if myGM.paint needs graphics g?

Comment: you can grab the graphics object from the event when your PictureBox appears on the form for the first time and then use this object as you like

Comment: Wait, what? How would I do that? All I understand so far is that I need to put myGM.paint(); in Timer.Tick

Comment: I am sorry for me probably seeming stupid, I just don't understand.

Comment: Come on, please help me understand

Comment: Now I get an error in my GameManager paint method, it says parameter is not vaild

Comment: You can't hold on to `e.Graphics` like that in a class level reference.  That graphics is managed by the framework and it gets disposed of automatically.  Only use it for the lifetime of that Paint() event.  It's o.k. to pass it to other subs, but you shouldn't keep a reference to it or dispose of it yourself...

Comment: It points at g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation()); in the paint method in GameManger and the error says Parameter is not valid.

Comment: @Idle_Mind is absolutely rigth, I have misread MSDN. So it is possible to operate e.Graphics only during event. In this way, you can try debug you code and find out if event is fired correctly and what is going in it.

Answer (score 1):

This has always worked for me in `PictureBoxes` and other `Controls`

```
PictureBox.Refresh();
PictureBox.Update();
```

OR

```
PictureBox.Update();
PictureBox.Refresh();
```

Although I can't remember which